# Administrator : TLS version KO?

Tags: tibco

I have one palette **SOAP Request Reply** in my project. My project works in Designer. It doesn't work after deployment in Administrator.

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to create secure client socket: Connection reset at [...]
<msg>An IOException was thrown while trying to execute the Http method</msg>
<msgCode>BW-HTTP-100300</msgCode>
```

I would like to confirm TLS version is OK. The SOAP server doesn't support TLS 1.0. 
**How to know and how to change TLS version in Administrator ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you have configured SSL in SOAP Request Reply.
If yes, is the folder path where all the Certificates being stored referred by Global Variable 'BW_GLOBAL_TRUSTED_CA_STORE'?